# Are there any positive odd integer solutions to $c^2=a^2-b^2+ab$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, rational-numbers

I got to this point after trying to solve a special case of the rational distance problem.

The general problem is as follows:

Consider the points $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)$.  Is there a point on the real plane where the distance to each point on that square is rational?

I was trying to prove that there is no solution when the point in question lies on the x axis.

After a lot of rearranging, I ended up with the diophantine equation, $c^2=a^2-b^2+ab$ where $a,b,c$ are all relatively prime to one another, and $a,b$ are odd?

My gut instinct tells me that there aren’t any nontrivial solutions, but I cant figure out how to prove it.

More generally, is there a way to determine if $c^2=xa^2+yab+zb^2$ has solutions in the positive integers, given $x,y,$ and $z$?

Edit: $a$ and $b$ are both odd.

Answer (score 4):

$$  \left( x^2 + xy - y^2 \right)^2 = X^2 + XY - Y^2  $$

where
$$   X = x^2 + y^2  $$
$$Y = 2xy + y^2  $$

Comment: Thanks! Is this a general form?

Comment: Yes. This is Dirichlet's method for Gauss composition.  There will be such a rule   for any form with the first coefficient $1,$  that is $(x^2 + Bxy + C y^2)^2  =  X^2 + BXY + C Y^2$    with $X=x^2 - Cy^2, \; \;  Y =2xy +By^2 $

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=a/c$ and $y=b/c$.  All rational points on $x^2 - y^2 + xy = 1$ are solutions.  Since $(-1, 0)$ is a known solution, consider all lines passing through that point with a slope of $m/n$:  $y=(x+1)m/n$. (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kcrsllei9b) For the intersection of that line and the hyperbola, if $(m,n)$ are integers, then $(x,y)$ must be rational.

Solving the intersection of the line and parabola gives

$$x=\frac{n^2+m^2}{n^2+mn-m^2}$$
$$y=\frac{2mn+m^2}{n^2+mn-m^2}$$

This gives all (primitive) solutions as
$$a = n^2 + m^2$$
$$b = 2mn + m^2$$
$$c = n^2 + mn - m^2$$

For example, if $m=1$ and $n=7$ then $(a,b,c) = (10,3,11)$.

---

If you are only interested in odd solutions, you can look at the 4 cases of $m$, $n$ even or odd.  Or more directly, $a = n^2 + m^2$ requires $m,n$ to have opposite parity, $b = 2mn + m^2$ forces $m$ odd and $n$ even, which forces $c = n^2 + mn - m^2$ to make $c$ odd.

So the odd solutions come from $m$ odd and $n$ even, such as $(m,n)=(1,4)$ yields $(a,b,c) = (17,9,19)$.

Comment: "*odd* integer" solutions...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I wonder if someone understands the general solution if they can't figure out how to restrict it to odd values, but I'll add it since requested.

Comment: I should probably mention this is an adaptation of a well known technique for finding pythagorean triples.

Answer (score 1):

$$\{a \to 240, b \to 72, c \to 264\}, 
\{a \to 338, b \to 48, c \to 358 \}, \{ a \to 73, b \to 57, c \to 79 \}$$

Comment: +1 , (10,3,11) is Smaller !

Comment: Thanks! You can reduce the first one down to $a=10, b=3, c=11$

Comment: The equation is homogenious, so you can reduce the 2nd solution, too.